# micronaut petstore a code segment from java to groovy

Tags: java, groovy, rx-java2, micronaut

The actual code [is here](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-examples/blob/master/petstore/offers/src/main/java/example/offers/OffersRepository.java#L199-L215)

```
private Function<String, Mono<? extends Offer>> keyToOffer(RedisReactiveCommands<String, String> commands) {
        return key -> {
            Flux<KeyValue<String, String>> values = commands.hmget(key, "price", "description");
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(3);
            return values.reduce(map, (all, keyValue) -> {
                all.put(keyValue.getKey(), keyValue.getValue());
                return all;
            })
                    .map(ConvertibleValues::of)
                    .flatMap(entries -> {
                        String description = entries.get("description", String.class).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No description"));
                        BigDecimal price = entries.get("price", BigDecimal.class).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No price"));
                        Flowable<Pet> findPetFlowable = petClient.find(key).toFlowable();
                        return Mono.from(findPetFlowable).map(pet -> new Offer(pet, description, price));
                    });
        };
    }
```

I have tried in a variety of different ways to convert above into groovy and all attempts so far not worked out too well. I wondered if anyone better with groovy could help

My attempt wasn't posted since the code itself firstly returns **Ambiguous code block** in Intelij and secondly looks totally wrong.

```
 private Function<String, Mono<? extends Orders>> keyToOrder(RedisReactiveCommands<String, String> commands) {
    return { key -> {
        Flux<KeyValue<String, String>> values = commands.hmget(key, "price", "description");
        Map map = [:]
        return values.reduce(map, (all, keyValue)= {all.put(keyValue.getKey(), keyValue.getValue());
            return all
        }).map({entries -> ConvertibleValues.of(entries)})
                .flatMap({entries -> {
            String description = entries.get("description", String.class).orElseThrow({ new IllegalStateException("No description")});
            BigDecimal price = entries.get("price", BigDecimal.class).orElseThrow({new IllegalStateException("No price")});
            Flowable<Item> findItemFlowable = itemClient.find(key).toFlowable();
            return Mono.from(findItemFlowable).map({item -> new Orders(item, description, price)});
        }});
    }}
}
```

When attempting to convert to groovy the biggest struggle appeared to be around:

```
return values.reduce(map, (all, keyValue)= {all.put(keyValue.getKey(), keyValue.getValue());
                    return all
```

This is nothing like what the original java code looked like and really unsure if it would even behave as it should. The issue I had was to find anything aorund RXJAVA Flux .reduce  written in groovy out there.

The Ambiguous code block is around this entire flatMap segment at the very bottom

```
 .flatMap({entries -> {
```

I haven't checked in this change nor did I post it since frankly it was embarrassing.

I have also come across:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html#collapseRxGroovy

```
numbers.reduce({ a, b -> a+b }).
```

and ended up with:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(3);
            return values.reduce({all, keyValue->
                all.put(keyValue.getKey(), keyValue.getValue());
                return all
        }).map({entries -> ConvertibleValues.of(entries)})
```

But this again looks wrong and doesn't really match what the java code was doing.

Final edit to suggest I have got Intelij to accept the code as groovy but not quite sure if it is what the java code was actually doing, since declared map is not even used:

```
private Function<String, Mono<? extends Orders>> keyToOrder(RedisReactiveCommands<String, String> commands) {
    Flux<KeyValue<String, String>> values = commands.hmget(key, "price", "description");
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(3);
        values.reduce({all, keyValue->
            all.put(keyValue.getKey(), keyValue.getValue());
            return all
    }).map({entries -> ConvertibleValues.of(entries)})
                .flatMap({entries ->  bindEntry(entries)});
    return values.key
}

private Mono<Orders> bindEntry(entries) {
    String description = entries.get("description", String.class).orElseThrow({ new IllegalStateException("No description")});
    BigDecimal price = entries.get("price", BigDecimal.class).orElseThrow({new IllegalStateException("No price")});
    Flowable<Item> findItemFlowable = itemClient.find(key).toFlowable();
    return Mono.from(findItemFlowable).map({item -> new Orders(item, description, price)});

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question here - do you want us to re-write this class for you?

Comment: Hi llya In short if above can be converted from java to groovy that would be great https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-java-groovy-comparison/blob/master/test-groovy/src/main/groovy/comparison.java.groovy/controller/OrdersRepository.groovy  - the first link is what I am trying from this code https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-java-groovy-comparison/blob/master/test-java/src/main/java/comparison/java/groovy/controller/OrdersRepository.java  - Simply trying to understand some of the more complex rxjava statements in java and how to do same under groovy

Comment: okay thank you for your input

Comment: If you have failing code, then please add your attempt and what errors you get to the question.  An potential answer can work from that then.

Comment: Thanks @cfrick I added in what I did last night but will start again today fresh and attempt it on a fresh start. It was embarrassing to put up what I had done so far why I left it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely issue you're facing is because Groovy doesn't support Java method references or lambdas.

The first line is returning a lambda

Java: `return key -> {`

Groovy: `return { key - >`

That is using a groovy closure that takes the key as the argument.

Other places that use method references need to be converted

Java: `.map(ConvertibleValues::of)`

Groovy: `.map({ values -> ConvertibleValues.of(values) })`

It seems like you have most of that worked out, however you specifically asked about the map not being used. That is because you simply aren't passing it to the method.

`values.reduce({all, keyValue->`
vs
`values.reduce(map, {all, keyValue ->`

Comment: Thank you James. Will give this a try a bit later when I get time.

Comment: `.map(ConvertibleValues::of)` actually corresponds to `.map(ConvertibleValues.&of)` in groovy